# Single login to moodle through mysite which contains moodle in subdirectory

Tags: php, curl, authentication, moodle

What I am doing is developing a site in my local system using WAMP server. It contain moodle directory in a subdirectory. website has its own database for user account and moodle has its own. On some suggestion I used External Database Authentication that works fine but what I want is when a user log in to website he should instantly login to moodle and if user logout from website he should be logged out from moodle and (vice versa if possible).

Currently what I am doing to accomplish this is - logging user in from the website and logging in moodle using curl and setting cookie externally. If I print curl response it shows moodle page with logged in user but if after login I redirect to home page where I have some link to moodle like 'MyCourse'. these link redirect to moodle login page with message "Session timed out. Please log...". My login code is ..

```
$r=mysqli_query($link, "select * from userinfo where username = '$uname' and password=SHA('$password')");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($r)>0)
    {
         $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://localhost/mysite/moodle/login/index.php");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username=$uname&password=$password&rememberusername=1&Login");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
        $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
        $response = curl_getinfo( $ch );
        curl_close ($ch);
        //print_r($response);
        preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^\r\n]*)/mi', $server_output, $ms);
        // print_r($result);
        $cookies = array();
        var_dump($ms);
         foreach ($ms[1] as $m) {
            list($name, $value) = explode('=', $m, 2);
            list($namevalue) = explode(';', $value, 1);
            setcookie($name, $namevalue, time()+3600*24, '/mysite/moodle', 'localhost');
        }
        //print_r($cookies);
        //print_r( $server_output);
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $_SESSION['logged_in']="yes";
        $_SESSION['uid']=$row['id'];
        //header('Location:home.php');
        exit(0);
    }else{
         echo 'Invalid username/password';
    }
```

Please suggest where I am doing wrong or if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: hi ashutosh did you finsih this work..if you finished canyou please explain me how you did that..

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at it myself but maybe have a look at the code for integrating Joomla with Moodle - http://www.joomdle.com/en/ - it claims to provide a seamless sign on between the 2 systems - http://www.joomdle.com/wiki/Single_Sign_On

Or CAS authentication - http://docs.moodle.org/25/en/CAS_server_(SSO)